# VBScript to Rename File with Specific Prefix in Folder

Tags: vbscript, file-rename

I have successfully created a VBScript that renames a file as required when it is the only file in the folder.  I cannot figure out how to have the script search past the most recent file.

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim fso, folder, file,  tmFile
 Dim folderName

 folderName     = "\\pcc\Int\PC\Inbox\"

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  
 Set tmFile = Nothing

 For each file In folder.Files    

 If (tmFile is Nothing) Then 
     Set tmFile = file
     Exit For
 End IF

 Next

 If InStr(tmfile.name, "TM") Then
     TmFile.Name = Replace(tmFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 End if
```

The above script correctly renames the file.

Here are a few modifications I have tried to go through all of the files in the folder to search for the file that has the prefix TM.  This will always be the only file with the TM prefix.

```
 For Each InStr(tmFile.name, "TM")  Then 
    tmFile.Name = Replace(tmFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 Exit for
```

and

```
 If tmFile.fileexists(tmFile.name, "TM")  Then 
     tmFile.Name = Replace(tmFile.Name, ".txt", "A.txt")
 End if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close with your `instr()`, it's just that you need to put that test within your already existing `For` loop:

```
Option Explicit

 Dim fso, folder, file,  tmFile
 Dim folderName

 folderName     = "\\pcc\Int\PC\Inbox\"

 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  
     
 For each file In folder.Files  
     If instr(file, "TM") > 0 THEN
         file.name = replace(file.name, ".txt", "A.txt")
     End IF
 Next
```

I've removed the `tmfile` variable since it's simply not needed here.

Comment: Thank you!  That did it and I will know for next time.  I appreciate your help.  :)

Comment: @JNevill Please correct the code in the replace function. It should be ```file.name = Replace(file.name, ".txt", "A.txt")```. You used a dot instead of a comma in the replace function...